# Javascript if clause won't work

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm having trouble with a javascript function that needs to take a global variable into account.

It's kind of a control mechanism I would like to implement, but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's the relevant code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var active = 0;

function SetEndTime(lngOpenPersonID,lngToDoID){
if(active = 0){
    alert('Time has been stopped');
}
else{
    var strURL = 'blabla';
    CallAJAXURL(strURL);
}
active = 0;
}
function SetStartTime(lngToDoID,lngToDoItemID,bitCountsForTotal){
if(active = 1){
    alert('Time has been started');
}
else{
    var strURL = 'blabla';
    CallAJAXURL(strURL);
}
active = 1;
}
```

When I call SetStartTime without doing anything else, I always get the alert. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not `(alert = 1)` .. its `( alert == 1 )`.. your condition says its always true -- your assigning alert to 1

Answer (score 4):

```
if (active == 0) {
```

You need **2** "=" characters to make a comparison operator. There's also `===` which performs an equality comparison without type promotion.

Your code is syntactically correct because an assignment operation is a valid expression.  The first `if` statement you had:

```
if (active = 0) {
```

will never be `true`, because the value of the expression is always zero. The second one:

```
if (active = 1) {
```

conversely is always `true` because the value is always one.